# erase windows on thinkpad computer

Tags: system-installation, thinkpad

I have a thinkpad computer T420, and installed ubuntu on it. Windows 7 was
previously installed on this computer. My first intention was to erase windows and install ubuntu. During the installation process of ubuntu, this procedure (erase windows and install ubuntu) is blocked by the system, and forced me to install ubuntu keeping windows. A friend of mine quite involved in linux/ubuntu told me once that this is a known problem. I definitely don't need windows, and want to make it disappear from my computer.

How could I proceed?

Comment: Have you tried booting the Ubuntu install media in MBR mode, as opposed to UEFI mode?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by, *"this procedure (erase windows and install ubuntu) is blocked by the system"* ?

Answer (score 1):

When I select 'Erase disk and install Ubuntu' that is also what the installer will do.

I am not sure, but maybe your Windows system is/was hibernated or semi-hibernated (alias fast startup), and the installer senses that there is something, that it is not supposed to touch.

---

Anyway I suggest the following:

- **Backup** at least the files (documents, pictures ...), that you cannot afford to lose: better safe than sorry.
- Boot into Windows and create **Windows recovery disks** 'just in case'.
- Boot from your Ubuntu install drive

  - **if you want to install a fresh Ubuntu system**

    - Start gparted and create a new partition table: <kbd>Device</kbd> - <kbd>Create partition table...</kbd>. GPT is the modern partition table and must be used if the drive is bigger than 2 TB. If you have specific ideas how to create partitions, create them now with gparted.
    - Start the installer and use the whole drive 'Erase disk and install Ubuntu' unless you have specific ideas how to create partitions. In that case, use 'Something else'.
    - Reboot
  - **if you want to keep your already installed Ubuntu system**

    - Start gparted and remove the Windows partition(s) but keep the EFI partition if there is such a partition
    - Use the unallocated space (that was used by Windows before) for a data partition with the ext4 file system. (There are other alternatives.)
    - Create a line in /etc/fstab that points to the data partition. Ask in a comment, if you need details.
    - Reboot the computer. It should boot into Ubuntu.
    - Run `sudo update-grub` to get a clean grub menu without a menuentry for Windows

Write a comment and ask if you need more help!